# Docker Nginx on port 80 with shared hosting

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to deploy nginx/gunicorn/django stack on a machine where several websites are hosted. And I can do it on any other ports than 80 port which eventually I need, because HTTP daemon is using that. And I am not aware of consequences of killing the httpd process. Before I deployed docker, php was running on this website with cpanel.

Processes using :80 port are

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22466/httpd 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      22466/httpd
```

Any tips or ideas?

Edit:
My config files for working 8000 port, when I change ports to 80 I have this problem that I am asking:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
      - ./src/media:/media
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dg01
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn mydjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: ps01
```

nginx conf

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {
  location /static/ {
      autoindex on;
      alias /static/;
  }

  location /media/ {
      autoindex on;
      alias /media/;
  }

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://web/;
  }
  listen 8000;
  server_name server_domain_here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In docker you can redirect port 80 that is used internally in the container to another port on the host.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 <your image>
```

then you will have no conflict on you host.

Comment: On my docker-compose.yml, I have port set "8000:8000" for nginx, should I remove that or that command will override it? Also, thanks for your effort to help

Comment: If you  are using docker-compose then you can change the redirect there. What does you docker-compose.yml look like ?

Comment: I added my nginx conf and docker-compose file. And as I mentioned in the post, it is for 8000 for now, and it is working properly. The problem occurs when I change all 8000 to 80, then it tells me port 80 is already allocated. Also when I try 80, I remove expose part from the docker compose since it is already exposed.

Comment: Well yes port 80 can only be used once.